# Grafana Alerting - how to link to query that triggered the alert

Tags: grafana

I am currently setting up Grafana Alerting for my org and a major pain point right now is that there does not appear to be a straightforward way to link to the query that triggered the alert in the first place.

Is that possible to achieve somehow, without setting up a dedicated Dashboards, Panels or Templates?

I guess I could set up Dashboards and Panels for all queries, or use elaborate templates to put together a query string, but that always requires to maintain the query in two places.

Comment: In Prometheus' alertmanager I believe this can be done using  `{{ (index .Alerts 0).GeneratorURL }}` in template. Seen [here](https://hodovi.cc/blog/creating-awesome-alertmanager-templates-for-slack/). Not sure if this appropriate for all data sources, though. Or if Grafana allows for such templating, But hope this can help you start digging.